# Determining the correct amount of bulk decoupling capacitance for a PWM LED driver

Tags: pwm, led-strip, decoupling-capacitor

I have a number of LED strips (the simple versions: 3 LED + resistor per "section")  that I want to modulate with a PWM driver at ~ 1kHz.  The design looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpmZZu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My expectation is that the capacitance C is going to be related to the output impedance of the 12V power supply, however I'm not sure how to determine the output impedance of the power supply.

If I could narrow down the impedance at 1kHz of the power supply, I could use that for a low pass filter.  However I'm not sure if there is a simpler way to figure out the correct bulk capacitance.

Comment: Have you determined that a capacitance is required at all?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:  I haven't.  At the moment,  I haven't chosen a power supply, so I can't tell if the capacitance is needed.  I'm designing the PCB for it at the moment, and am trying to figure out if I should add room for the rather large caps I believe I will need.  Another way of phrasing this might be "when is bulk capacitance needed?"

Comment: The length of the wires between the power supply and LED strip will make a big difference on how much C you need.

Comment: @Daniel: care to elaborate?  I'm aware of the inductance of the wires, but didn't think it would be a huge deal at 1kHz (even taking into account harmonics)

Comment: I have experienced this many times, debugging hardware, getting strange results, then cutting the supply wires down which makes the problem disappear. You have the inductance, and also the wire resistance is a problem when a partially bypassed device tries to take a large gulp of current, which can be 10s of amps.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks.  I'll have to keep that in mind.  Maybe get a power supply with sense pins to try and mitigate that.

Comment: @AndrewSpott Just put capacitance where you need it, and if you have a higher-impedance pinch point (like feed wires or a wire harness) make sure that you're locally bypassed. Sense wires probably will not improve this problem since it needs to respond very quickly.

Comment: @Daniel: "put capacitance where you need it".  That sounds very simple, but I'm not sure "where I need it", which is part of what this question is about.

Comment: If things don't work the way you want, you're going to have to experimentally figure out what the ripple voltage is at each point, then figure out of that is ok for you. If it's not, you can estimate the current pulse magnitude and duration with an oscilloscope and a small resistor, then place the appropriate amount of capacitance there to fulfill the current pulse. Or you can do what most people do: guess, and if it works leave it alone!

Comment: @Daniel: that is the plan.  However I would love to get as much info as possible and try and get it right the first time before I guess... :)

Comment: You've already spent too much time on that. Get out of your head and get on the bench! (You're asking people to estimate stuff *you* need to measure. Theory can explain stuff, but it can't predict things when you have no idea what the parameters are)

Comment: @Daniel I understand the sentiment.  Unfortunately a combination of being a poor graduate student (can't do too many prototypes) and being a theoretical physicist gives me a predilection for theory when possible... or at least trying to understand where things might go wrong.

Comment: As for Ignacio's question whether OP has determined if a cap is required at all: a cap on the output of an SMPS driving a PWM'd strip of LEDs can help with PSU whining sounds even if it's not required to make the _light_ output smooth. Perhaps that could be worked into the question...

Comment: Nobody else mentioned, so I will, that twisting the power lines between the LED driver and the strip not only minimizes the inductive loop,.but also cancels out much of the inductance, which may reduce whining sounds, and how much capacitance is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VA rating on 12V supply must exceed stripled Watt rating.  These are design for automotive 14.2 at max brightness.  These are not highly efficiently with a threshold of around 9V and are rated in Watts per foot or per meter.

The problem with many wall wort supplies is the internal cap may not be rated for the pulsed ripple current you intend to apply and prefer to be run at constant load .

You can use a surplus PC PSU at 12V or perhaps a universal laptop charger which is less robust but may have a selection for 15V at 4A or more.

to choose a cap for unknown flakey supply, it must handle the RMS current you intend to switch. So if 5App 50% assume 2.5A and choose a cap rated >3A rms ripple current.

to choose c value at 1K or 10kHz compute C for 10 cycles using R=Watts/(I^2) as the load is quasi linear with series R's.

e.g at 1kHz  and RC=10cyc/1kHz=10ms or 1ms @10kHz

- thus if strip leds are 5A, for cap sag of 10%V in 1ms @10kHz,
- Ic=Cdv/dt so C=5A*1ms/1.4V=3600uF rated at >=16V

3600uF/16V is not avail, but 2200uF is avail [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/aluminum-polymer-capacitors/132402?k=&pkeyword=&pv13=126&pv13=135&pv13=157&pv13=166&pv63=489&FV=fff40002%2Cfff80532&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500). Ripple current =8.1Arms radial leaded $1.5 , get two

- 1kHz would need 10x bigger cap.
  Mosfet should have RdsOn<<100mOhm@5A for no heatsink @0.5W dissipation, lower is better and can be driven by NE555 PWM clock.

Comment: Why do you choose the diodes as the R in the RC vs the output impedance of the power supply?

Comment: Good question, but I made no assumption on the Zout of the supply, only that VA rating exceeds W load for same 12V. It could be low Zout from a DC-DC or higher unregulated source, which doesn't matter since stripLEDs are designed with large (e.g. 68-82Ohm) series R's per series string, then replicated in parallel to accommodate 11 to 14.2V typical range with varying brightness.  The series R in the stripLEDs will always be larger than Zout of compatible 12V supply and may fail with an early lifetime. (e.g. <1yr). Thus you were wise to ask about sizing a suitable cap., but not 1kHz. maybe (25k)

Comment: "Thus you were wise to ask about sizing a suitable cap., but not 1kHz. maybe (25k)"  Do you mean I should use a 25kHz PWM, or that I don't need to worry about caps at 1kHz, and do at 25kHz.  If I understand you correctly, then the latter is more true than the former.

Comment: 1kHz is low , higher f results in lower C, even wiser is add Amp rated choke to source to raise source impedance with PWM to reduce ripple current on unknown source, then smaller C and lower ripple current. aka. Buck reg. dimmer.

Comment: Why do you choose 10 cycles for C?  I would think a single cycle would be good enough.  To make sure the low pass is good enough at that frequency?

Comment: Unfortunately, 1kHz is the driver that I have available.  At 1kHz I also don't have to worry about using a driver for my mosfets (the PWM chip can drive them at that frequency for a reasonable rise time) and I can mitigate the necessity of the external caps by shifting the different PWM phases around.

Comment: now u tell me ...

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, so don't feel like it was wasted effort.  I'm also not sure how well that phase shifting is going to help:  for small numbers of strips and low duty cycles it isn't going to be super useful, which is the likely case.

Comment: Could someone go over that answer and make it a little more readable for those of us who are not so well-versed in math and the lingo of electrical engineering? Things like "stripled" or "c value" I can edit myself. But what does the author mean by "cap sag" and "Cdv/dt" or "Arms"? As for the price of the suggested capacitor for OP's example, I'd remove that since prices are too much in flux these days...

Comment: Also, how does the author arrive at that 1.4V figure? Is the the ripple voltage he guesstimates OP's PSU to have? Sounds too high for a 12V supply...?

Comment: Ic = cap current = C [F] * dV [V] / dt [sec] ... standard cap equation  Amps (rms) = Arms